# Problema com hover em CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma tabela e quero que cada célula seja realçada quando o mouse estiver sobre.
No entanto, não está funcionando. Deve-se considerar que estou utilizando `bootstrap` como base para os estilos da página e, por isso, acredito que seja conflito entre meu `css` e o do `bootstrap`.

A tabela está definida da seguinte forma:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="info_table"><div onclick="invDir(0);" id="gpio0">-</div></td>
        <td align="center" class="info_table"><div id="gpio1">-</div></td>
        <td align="center" class="info_table"><div id="gpio2">-</div></td>
        <td align="center" class="info_table"><div id="gpio3">-</div></td>
        <td align="center" class="info_table"><div id="gpio4">-</div></td>
        ...
```

Defini a classe `info_table` para dar o realce e impedir que o valor seja selecionado.
E esse é o `css` de `info_table`:

```
.info_table 
{
    width: 5%;
    color: #d44637;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.info_table  : hover
{
    background-color: #f1c40f;
}
```

O problema é que simplesmente o `hover` não funciona.

OBS: O conteúdo das `div's` gpio* é carregado dinamicamente.

Comment: O seu código tem espaços aqui? `.info_table  : hover` - não pode ter, deve ser `.info_table:hover`

Comment: O @Sergio tem razão, o problema é exatamente esse. http://jsfiddle.net/LrXcz/

Comment: @Sergio poste uma resposta :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto, vou esperar pela resposta do Lucas, não tenho a certeza que o problema seja só esse. O boostrap é como uma firewall, às vezes é díficil fazer o que se quer :)

Comment: @Sergio foi o espaço mesmo. Poste sua resposta.

Comment: Evite utilizar espaços entre as classes
ex: figure.foto_legenda:hover OBS:(Em alguns navegadores não funcionou no meu código)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para usar um seletor `:hover` no elemento `<td>` ele deve estar colado à classe `.info_table`. Assim pode usar, sem espaços:

```
.info_table:hover{
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vZLLR/)

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que o boostrap esteja sobrescrevendo seu CSS. Tente colocar o `!importante`na frente da regra `:hover`. Ex:

```
.info_table:hover
{
    background-color: #f1c40f !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que tenha algo sobrepondo seu atributo de cor-de-fundo. Use o Inspecionador do navegador pra olhar quem está anulando seu código.***Mas antes disso, tenta usar a classe `info_table` na `DIV` quem está dentro do `TD`.